# Arranging an array in ascending order w/ a string array & int array

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I've been working on this for a few hours and have tried looking around the internet for a better solution, but I'm having trouble finding an answer for my specific problem.

The task is... **Count the number of characters in each name, and sort them from least letters, to most letters.**

The format they must be sorted in goes as follows:

**Name1 - Count1**

**Name2 - Count2**

**[...]**

Now, the problem that I'm having is: I can successfully arrange an `int array[]` into ascending order, however I need the `string array[]` to correspond to the `int array[]` and output side by side.

Below is the following code that I have. I've tried using my own knowledge to solve this problem to the best of my ability. If anyone could point me in the right direction (not solve it for me), or explain why my `while` function isn't working as I expect. I would greatly appreciate it!~

```
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 7           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    int alphaCount[26];
    int sortedCount[26];
    int temp;
    string temp2;
    string sortedNames[26];
    string t;
 
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
        string t = n.names[i];
        t.erase(remove_if(t.begin(), t.end(), isspace), t.end());
        alphaCount[i] = t.size();
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        sortedCount[i] = alphaCount[i];
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 26; j++) {
            if (sortedCount[i] > sortedCount[j]) {
                temp = sortedCount[i];
                sortedCount[i] = sortedCount[j];
                sortedCount[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
 
    int i = 0;
 
    while (i < 26) {
        int j = 1;
        while (j < 26) {
            if (sortedCount[i] == n.names[j].length()) {
                cout << n.names[j] << " - " << sortedCount[i] << endl;
                i++;
            }
            if (sortedCount[i] != n.names[j].length()) {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
 
    systemClear();
}
```

**If you wish to look at all the code, here is the complete cpp file. You're looking specifically at Routine 7**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
 
using namespace std;
 
struct file {
    string names[26];
};
 
void systemClear();
void routineOne(file& n);
void routineTwo(file& n);
void routineThree(file& n);
void routineFour(file& n);
void routineFive(file& n);
void routineSix(file& n);
void routineSeven(file& n);
void routineEight(file& n);
 
int main()
{
    file n;
 
    //Function Execution
    routineOne(n);
    routineTwo(n);
    routineThree(n);
    routineFour(n);
    routineFive(n);
    routineSix(n);
    routineSeven(n);
    routineEight(n);
}
 
void systemClear() {
    short a = 0;
 
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter any number to continue: ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a != 0) {
        system("cls");
        return;
    }
    else {
        system("cls");
        return;
    }
}
 
void restart() {
    char a = 0;
 
    cout << "\n\nWould you like to restart the program? (y/n): ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 'y') {
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
    else {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\nThe program will now close, thank you\n\n";
        return;
    }
}
 
void routineOne(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 1           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Student.txt");
 
    inFile.ignore(12);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        getline(inFile, n.names[i]);
        inFile.ignore(1);
    }
 
    cout << "The input file has successfully been passed to an array.";
    systemClear();
}
 
void routineTwo(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 2           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    int x = 1;
    int y = 25;
 
    while (y != 13) {
        cout << n.names[x] << endl;
        x++;
        cout << n.names[y] << endl;
        y--;
    }
 
    cout << n.names[13] << endl;
 
    systemClear();
}
 
void routineThree(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 3           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    //I attempted an algorithm I found, however I couldn't get it to function properly (Is this the proper way of solving this problem?)
    cout << n.names[24] << endl;
    cout << n.names[14] << endl;
    cout << n.names[13] << endl;
    cout << n.names[22] << endl;
    cout << n.names[4] << endl;
    cout << n.names[16] << endl;
    cout << n.names[25] << endl;
    cout << n.names[21] << endl;
    cout << n.names[9] << endl;
    cout << n.names[19] << endl;
    cout << n.names[6] << endl;
    cout << n.names[12] << endl;
    cout << n.names[7] << endl;
    cout << n.names[2] << endl;
    cout << n.names[11] << endl;
    cout << n.names[20] << endl;
    cout << n.names[17] << endl;
    cout << n.names[23] << endl;
    cout << n.names[3] << endl;
    cout << n.names[8] << endl;
    cout << n.names[18] << endl;
    cout << n.names[5] << endl;
    cout << n.names[15] << endl;
    cout << n.names[10] << endl;
    cout << n.names[1] << endl;
 
    systemClear();
}
 
void routineFour(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 4           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    //I attempted an algorithm I found, however I couldn't get it to function properly (Is this the proper way of solving this problem?)
    cout << n.names[24] << endl;
    cout << n.names[14] << endl;
    cout << n.names[13] << endl;
    cout << n.names[22] << endl;
    cout << n.names[4] << endl;
    cout << n.names[16] << endl;
    cout << n.names[25] << endl;
    cout << n.names[21] << endl;
    cout << n.names[9] << endl;
    cout << "James N Blythe" << endl;
    cout << n.names[19] << endl;
    cout << n.names[6] << endl;
    cout << n.names[12] << endl;
    cout << n.names[7] << endl;
    cout << n.names[2] << endl;
    cout << n.names[11] << endl;
    cout << n.names[20] << endl;
    cout << n.names[17] << endl;
    cout << n.names[23] << endl;
    cout << n.names[3] << endl;
    cout << n.names[8] << endl;
    cout << n.names[18] << endl;
    cout << n.names[5] << endl;
    cout << n.names[15] << endl;
    cout << n.names[10] << endl;
    cout << n.names[1] << endl;
 
    systemClear();
}
 
void routineFive(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 5           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    string oddNames[12];
    int j = 0;
 
    for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
            i++;
            oddNames[j] = n.names[i];
            j++;
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        cout << oddNames[i] << endl;
    }
 
    systemClear();
}
 
void routineSix(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 6           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    cout << "???";
 
    systemClear();
 
}
 
void routineSeven(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 7           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    int alphaCount[26];
    int sortedCount[26];
    int temp;
    string temp2;
    string sortedNames[26];
    string t;
 
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
        string t = n.names[i];
        t.erase(remove_if(t.begin(), t.end(), isspace), t.end());
        alphaCount[i] = t.size();
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        sortedCount[i] = alphaCount[i];
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 26; j++) {
            if (sortedCount[i] > sortedCount[j]) {
                temp = sortedCount[i];
                sortedCount[i] = sortedCount[j];
                sortedCount[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
 
    int i = 0;
 
    while (i < 26) {
        int j = 1;
        while (j < 26) {
            if (sortedCount[i] == n.names[j].length()) {
                cout << n.names[j] << " - " << sortedCount[i] << endl;
                i++;
            }
            if (sortedCount[i] != n.names[j].length()) {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
 
    systemClear();
}
 
void routineEight(file& n) {
    cout << setw(34) << setfill('#') << "#\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << "#           Routine 8           #\n";
    cout << "#" << setw(33) << setfill(' ') << "#\n";
    cout << setw(35) << setfill('#') << "\n\n";
 
    restart();
}
```

Comment: could you please take a look at `std::sort` and its comparator function? that function would just compare argument strings' lengths and do the replacement work for you

Comment: Are you required to have an array of names and an array of numbers? This sort of task is much easier if you have a structure that aggregates name and number and have a single array of that structure.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski It's not comparing string lengths, it's only counting letters. Doing this count on every comparison would be very inefficient.

Comment: Tactical note: You almost never want to show all of the code. You want to show a little tiny program that demonstrates the problem with as little extra fluff as possible. Making this tiny program allows you to narrow in on the mistake and usefully ends early when you spot and fix the bug yourself. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: @Barmar ah right, I read that wrong - the precomputed pair or whatever would be preferable then

Comment: Side note: `//I attempted an algorithm I found, however I couldn't get it to function properly (Is this the proper way of solving this problem?)` This would be another question, but before you ask us ask yourself: "With nothing but the name `routineThree` and code that I know doesn't work right, are potential helpers able to determine what the code is supposed to do so they can help me fix the code?"

Comment: @user4581301 This comment was focused towards my professor, I had it added in there for when I submit the assignment he can see it and get back with me. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: @user4581301 Also, thank you. Sorry, I'm a bit new to StackOverflow (As I'm a CSC102 student). I was just trying to get the question out there in the best format I knew how. I'll definitely use this in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Given what was said in the comments, it'd be preferable for you to first precompute what you want to compare by (unique characters in string) together with strings.
Then, with this *enriched* input, you can just sort it, by comparing that computed attribute.
After you get your results, you can just remove what you sorted by.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// Counts unique chars in string.
int count_chars(const std::string& arg) {
        std::set<char> chars;
        for (auto i = 0; i < arg.size(); i++) {
                chars.insert(arg[i]);
        }
        return chars.size();
}

// Change input vector into enriched vector, keeping string with number of its unique chars.
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> process(const std::vector<std::string>& arg) {
        std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> result = {};
        for (const auto& e : arg) {
                std::pair<std::string, int> with_count = { e, count_chars(e) };
                result.push_back(with_count);
        }
        return result;
}

int main() {
        const auto i1 = "bbbccc";
        const auto i2 = "aaaabbbbccccdddddeeeeeefffffggghhh";
        const auto i3 = "aaa";

        // This is our input.
        const std::vector<std::string> input = { i1, i2, i3 };

        // This is our input, but this time the object stored also has the unique chars counted.
        std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> precomputed = process(input);

        // This is our sort section.
        std::sort(precomputed.begin(), precomputed.end(), [](const auto a, const auto b) {
                // This comparison will appear somewhere in middle of manually-written sort code.
                return a.second < b.second;
        });

        // 'precomputed' is now sorted by its second attribute (unique chars' count), so we can just take the real input (first field of pair).
        std::vector<std::string> output = {};
        for (const auto& e : precomputed) {
                output.push_back(e.first);
        }

        for (const auto& e : output) {
                std::cout << e << std::endl;
        }
}
```

with result being:

```
aaa
bbbccc
aaaabbbbccccdddddeeeeeefffffggghhh
```

The above example uses standard libraries - given that you're still learning, your professor most probably requires you to learn how to:

- bind string with its "metric" (read about `struct` - I used `std::pair` from standard library here);
- how to compute how many unique chars are there in string - I just used a set, but most probably you need to count it "manually" with 26-elem array or so;
- how to sort (I used `std::sort`) - you might start with trivial bubble sort, you just need to `compare` the two structs/pairs on your own.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate the response and the work behind it. I'm going to be completely honest, we haven't learned a majority of these things yet, neither in my CSC101 class. (I feel like we're really behind in general, as most of the things that I know I've googled/etc). The **entire** csc102 class is focusing solely on encapsulation. Nothing more than that. I slightly understand the sort function, but not to the extent to use it, and I don't fully understand vectors.

Comment: I'm gonna preface that I don't expect you to explain any of them to me, I just wanted to tell you that I appreciate the effort put forth. My current plan of action (though poorly optimized), is to use the same sort function I used to sort the `int array` except using sortedNames[i].length()

Comment: Right, I'm afraid that in such case you're expected (required?) to keep two vectors instead of single vector-of-two-attributes. So something like `vector<string> input` with input data and precomputed `vector<int> lengths` for whatever you needed. And then just inside the sort code you'd do `if (length[i] < length[j]) { swap(input, i, j); swap(lengths, i, j); }`

Comment: Yeah, our class sadly is pretty behind where I'm at. I'm not specifically sure if it's specifically required, as far as I was given instruction I was just told "solve the problems". However, my problem comes into my general understanding of the concepts and having to explain them to the rest of the class sometimes whenever they need help. I don't wanna try to explain something that I don't completely understand the use of yk

Comment: Neither CSC101 or CSC102 has gone into much detail pertaining to sort() or vectors, so all I know is the few algo/concepts that I've used them in. Haven't really been explained what they are or what they're function is yet. (partially my fault for not looking too far into it)